# requests module could not be read - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, pip

I can't import request module. It gives an error while importing and the error states that it cannot find the module. I installed the module but still facing the same issue. I check with (pip list) command and the request module seems to be registered. I also updated the pip command. the error still persists.

## importing the requests library

```
import requests
  
# defining the api-endpoint 
API_ENDPOINT = "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"
  
# your API key here
API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        
# your source code here
source_code = '''
print("Hello, world!")
a = 1
b = 2
print(a + b)
'''
  
# data to be sent to api
data = {'api_dev_key':API_KEY,
        'api_option':'paste',
        'api_paste_code':source_code,
        'api_paste_format':'python'}
  
# sending post request and saving response as response object
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)
  
# extracting response text 
pastebin_url = r.text
print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url)
```

Comment: Are you inside of an environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have installed it for the correct version of python. If you have many python installations on your system, it can get difficult.
So if you are running your script with a specific version, ex. python 3.8, you will have to install requests for that version.
In this example, run

```sh
python3.8 -m pip install requests
```

Try python2 or python3 too with the -m option.

Also, if you're on windows, use the `py` python launcher.

Like:

```sh
py -3 -m pip install requests
```

If you're inside a virtual environment or running docker, then the story is completely different...

Please refer to this: [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)